# MYSQL ERROR 1247 (42S22) at line 1: Reference 'total' not supported (reference to group function)

Tags: sql, mysql

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/contest-leaderboard/problem?isFullScreen=true

The total score of a hacker is the sum of their maximum scores for all of the challenges. Write a query to print the hacker_id, name, and total score of the hackers ordered by the descending score. If more than one hacker achieved the same total score, then sort the result by ascending hacker_id. Exclude all hackers with a total score of 0 from your result.

The following tables contain contest data:

Hackers: The hacker_id is the id of the hacker, and name is the name of the hacker.

Submissions: The submission_id is the id of the submission, hacker_id is the id of the hacker who made the submission, challenge_id is the id of the challenge for which the submission belongs to, and score is the score of the submission.

I was trying to solve this hackerrank problem and I can't figure out what mistake am I making.

```
select h.hacker_id,h.name,sum(s.score) as total
from hackers as h inner join submissions as s on h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id,h.name
having total in
(
    select sum(max(score))
    from 
    (   select max(score)
        from submissions
        group by hacker_id,challenge_id
    )as highest
    group by hacker_id
    having sum(total)<>0
)
order by sum(s.score),h.hacker_id;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `where total in` perhaps, having expects an expression like you've used used in the subquery

Comment: All questions on this forum need to be self-contained. So please add whatever information you've linked to directly to your question, as editable text. Thanks

Comment: @Stu no it is still not working

Comment: *`having sum(total)<>0`* - you cannot aggregate external reference. *`sum(max(score))`* - you cannot use nested aggregftion. There is no output columns aliases - you cannot refer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total` comes from the `select` in the outer query, so you couldn't use it in the `having`, nor does it make sense to use it again in the inner `having`.

You also can't use `sum(max(score))`. I suspect you actually meant to use a column alias on the innermost query and then refer to it again in the intermediate level.

Either way, this doesn't look right. There is no need for the extra self-join on `submission`, you can do it in without that. You just need to pre-aggregate the max scores, then join it.

```
select
  h.hacker_id,
  h.name,
  s.total
from hackers as h
join (
    select
      s.hacker_id,
      sum(s.max_score) as total
    from 
    (
        select
          s.hacker_id,
          max(s.score) as max_score
        from submissions as s
        group by
          s.hacker_id,
          s.challenge_id
    ) as s
    group by
      s.hacker_id
    having sum(s.max_score) > 0
) as s on s.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
order by
  s.total desc,
  h.hacker_id;
```

You can also do it in just two levels, but then you need to go back to aggregating on `hacker_id, name`, which may be inefficient.

```
select
  h.hacker_id,
  h.name,
  sum(s.max_score) as total
from hackers as h
join (
    select
      s.hacker_id,
      max(s.score) as max_score
    from submissions as s
    group by
      s.hacker_id,
      s.challenge_id
) as s on s.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
group by
  h.hacker_id,
  h.name
having sum(s.max_score) > 0
order by
  s.total desc,
  h.hacker_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The original query contained several inconsistencies, notably in the use of the `HAVING` clause with `SUM` and `MAX`. Use a `LEFT JOIN` to ensure that all hackers from the "**Hackers**" table are included in the results, even if they haven't submitted solutions. Then, use a subquery to obtain the maximum score for each (`hacker_id`, `challenge_id`) pair. Finally, **group the results by** `hacker_id` and `name`, calculate the **sum** of the **maximum scores** (`total_score`), **exclude** hackers with a `total_score of 0`, and then **order the result by** `total_score` **in descending order**, **followed by** **hacker_id** **in ascending order** in case of a tie in `total_score`.

```
SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name, COALESCE(SUM(s.score), 0) AS total_score
FROM Hackers h
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT hacker_id, challenge_id, MAX(score) AS score
    FROM Submissions
    GROUP BY hacker_id, challenge_id
) s ON h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
HAVING total_score <> 0
ORDER BY total_score DESC, h.hacker_id;
```